# Просуммировать числа в цикле от 1 до 100

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

```
a = 0
while a < 101:
    print(a)
    a = a + 1
```

Как записать суму чисел 1+...100

Comment: `sum(range(101))`

Comment: Вы хотите вывести значение суммы 1+...+100 или вывести в ряд саму сумму в виде "1+2+3+...+99+100"?

Comment: Значение суммы и в ряд тоже но в отдельной программе

Comment: Пожалуйста мне срочно

Answer (score 4):

Без явных циклов:

```
end = 100
seq = range(end + 1)
s = sum(seq)

print('+'.join(map(str, seq)))
print("Сумма:", s)
```

Результат:

```
0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20+21+22+23+24+25+26+27+28+29+30+31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39+40+41+42+43+44+45+46+47+48+49+50+51+52+53+54+55+56+57+58+59+60+61+62+63+64+65+66+67+68+69+70+71+72+73+74+75+76+77+78+79+80+81+82+83+84+85+86+87+88+89+90+91+92+93+94+95+96+97+98+99+100
Сумма: 5050
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = 0
end = 100
a = start
s = 0

while a < end+1:
    if a == end:
        print(end, end='\n')
    else:
        print(a, end='+')

    s += a
    a = a + 1

print("Сумма:", s)
```

Comment: но сумма же неправильная получается 101

Comment: @ andreymal ладно простите

Comment: @igorrybka да, действительно, поправил код, теперь должно быть все нормально.

Comment: Все спасибо вам огромное

Comment: @igorrybka попробуйте открыть учебник по питону и найти ответ на этот вопрос в нём

Comment: @АртемПоликарпов, `a = a + 1` -> `a += 1` и `while a < end+1:` -> `while a <= end:`

Comment: @igorrybka, `s += a` это тоже самое что `s = s + a`, это касается и других операторов, например: `s *= a` -> `s = s * a`

Comment: а можно ли сделать что бы числа мог ввести я через int(input())?? только что бы сума была правильная

Comment: @igorrybka, `start = int(input()); end = int(input())`

Comment: @Артем Поликарпов нет ну это то я понял а я не понимаю почему у меня оно считает неправильно, допустим я ввел числа start = 2, end = 6 но вместо 20 оно выдает 25

Comment: @igorrybka, у меня выводит 20.